# Are these two integrals equal for all $n$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I am trying to prove that these two integrals are equal
$$
\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\dots\int_0^\infty 
\exp(-x z_1-z_1z_2-z_2z_3-\dots-z_{n-1}z_{n}-z_n)
x^{c_1-1}  
z_1^{c_1+c_2-1} z_2^{c_2+c_3-1} \dots z_{n}^{c_n+c_{n+1}-1}
dz_1 dz_2 \dots dz_{n}
$$
$$
\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\dots\int_0^\infty
\exp(-x ^{w_n} z_1-z_1z_2-z_2z_3-\dots-z_{n-1}z_{n}-z_n)
x^{{w_n}\,c_{n+1}-1}  
z_n^{c_1+c_2-1} z_{n-1}^{c_2+c_3-1} \dots z_{1}^{c_n+c_{n+1}-1}
dz_1 dz_2 \dots dz_{n}
$$
where $x>0,c_n>0,\forall n$ and
$$w_n = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{even}\,\,n  \\ -1 & \text{odd}\,\,n \end{cases}.$$

Using Mathematica, I was able to prove up to $n=5$, but is this valid for all $n$?

Comment: Just wondering:  Why do you state your question with a $w$ only to restrict it to $w=1$?  Isn't that a confusing waste of time?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, $w=1$ only for even values of $n$ and $w=-1$ only for odd values of $n$

Comment: I've rolled back your removal of the exponentials (resulting in *diverging* integrals).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically $w_n=(-1)^n$. Just substitute $z_k=x^{(-1)^k}y_{n-k+1}$ in the first integral:
$$
xz_1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}z_kz_{k+1}+z_n=x^{(-1)^n}y_1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}y_ky_{k+1}+y_n,
\\
x^{c_1-1}\prod_{k=1}^{n}z_k^{c_k+c_{k+1}-1}\,dz_1\cdots dz_n=x^{c-1}\prod_{k=1}^{n}y_{n-k+1}^{c_k+c_{k+1}-1}\,dy_1\cdots dy_n,\\
c:=c_1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^k(c_k+c_{k+1})=(-1)^nc_{n+1},
$$
and your equality follows immediately.